# MongoDB error trying to 'docker build' my Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

Model:

```
@Document("users")
public class User {
...
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, ObjectId> {
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    ...

}
```

When I run my application from `IDE` with the following `application.properties`:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=...
spring.data.mongodb.password=...
spring.data.mongodb.database=mydb
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

everything works.

However, my goal is to deploy my app and `MongoDB` with `Docker`/`Kubernetes`, so I use the following `application.properties`:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
spring.data.mongodb.password=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
spring.data.mongodb.database=${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGODB_HOSTNAME}
```

where the variables starting with `$` are the values that I set in Kubernetes YAML files.
But when I call `docker build -t user-service:v1 ./user-service` I get many errors.
Before `MongoDB` integration in my app, the `docker build` command worked.

These are the errors I got after `docker build` command:

```
2022-12-17T13:11:00.018Z  WARN 72 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.ecommerceapp.userservice.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
2022-12-17T13:11:00.034Z  INFO 72 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-17T13:11:00.058Z ERROR 72 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository': Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.ecommerceapp.userservice.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]

    ...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.ecommerceapp.userservice.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1663) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 92 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not contain slashes, dots, spaces, quotes, or dollar signs
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:793) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:543) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 105 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not contain slashes, dots, spaces, quotes, or dollar signs
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 115 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport]: Factory method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' threw exception with message: Database name must not contain slashes, dots, spaces, quotes, or dollar signs
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 129 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must not contain slashes, dots, spaces, quotes, or dollar signs
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:122) ~[spring-core-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDatabaseFactorySupport.<init>(MongoDatabaseFactorySupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.java:75) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.<init>(SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory.java:64) ~[spring-data-mongodb-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.mongoDatabaseFactory(MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 130 common frames omitted
```

YAML files:

service-db-configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: user-service-db-env-file
```

service-db-secret-file

```
apiVersion: v1
stringData:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: pippo
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: palla
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: db-secret-file
type: Opaque
```

db-service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-service-db
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
  selector:
    app: user-service-db
```

db-deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-service-db
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-service-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-service-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user-service-db
          image: mongo:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: user-service-db-env-file
            - secretRef:
                name: db-secret-file
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/db
              name: user-service-db-volume
      volumes:
        - name: user-service-db-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /user-service-db-volume
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

service-configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  MONGODB_HOSTNAME: user-service-db
  MONGODB_PORT: "27017"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: user-service-env-file
```

service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: user-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: user-service
```

deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-service
      annotations:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user-service
          image: user-service:v1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: user-service-db-env-file
            - configMapRef:
                name: user-service-env-file
            - secretRef:
                name: db-secret-file
```

ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: spring-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "Content-Type"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: airline-management-system.app.loc
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /users(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: user-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Comment: That seems like your Dockerfile is trying to actually run your application; that doesn't seem correct.  (It won't be able to reach the database, and it seems unusual to need to contact the database in the process of packaging a jar file.) What does the Dockerfile look like?

Comment: This is my Dockerfile:

`FROM maven:3-openjdk-17 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/target/user-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ./user-service.jar
CMD java -jar user-service.jar`

Before integrating MongoDB in my app (@Document annotation, application.properties, etc.), docker build command worked with this Dockerfile.

Comment: (In your deployment environment you can directly set environment variables like `$SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST`; you don't need to set Spring properties just to relay environment variables.)

Comment: When you read the exception you have a problem of setting the env variables , What does the configuration Kube yaml look like ?

Comment: @devskillup i just put the yaml files in the question body. I think the problem could be that I can't access the MongoDB cluster, so either it's a credential problem or wrong syntax (in the application.properties) or the database isn't exposed correctly, I don't know...

Comment: I got the yaml files from my professor's repository. But he, on the Spring-boot side, was using Java 8 and the MongoClient class, while I'm using Java 17 and the application.properties. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: Question: before you run the command **docker build ...** , if you apply the config like this : **kubectl apply -f service-db-configmap.yaml  -f service-db-secret-file.yaml -f service-configmap.yaml** ?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I solved using Java 11 instead of Java 17